# 500 (Internal Server Error) in AJAX function that works correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two buttons(#shownum1, #shownum2), that run a function (increment) when clicked.  I can see that the values are correctly incremented in the database which means that it works, but in the console I see this:

> GET http://localhost:3000/increment?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
function increment(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/increment',
        data: {'id': <%= @voiture.id %>}
    }); 
}


$('#shownum').on('click',function (){
    increment();
});
$('#shownum2').on('click',function (){
    increment();
});
```

The increment root:

```
get '/increment' => 'voitures#increment'
```

and finally the function increment :

```
def increment
  Voiture.increment_counter(:compteur, 1)
end
```

I'm quite sure it's all about the increment function.. i don't usually use AJAX. Thanks a lot !

Comment: you should check rails log (log/development.log) and you Chrome development console to debug your issue

Comment: that helps! i got this : ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template voitures/increment, but it's ok form since i don't need it.. What sould i do?

Comment: You might find it helpful to put a binding.pry in your `increment` method and step through the code in the terminal window your Rails server is running in. More info on binding.pry can be found here: http://pryrepl.org/

Comment: Maybe try rendering something back to the client? Something like: `head :no_content` after your `increment_counter` line. Or if there's a value you'd like to send down use something like `render json: your_value, status: :created`.

Comment: @Remis07 I've answered you question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of GET method, you should use POST method, then modify you code like following one:

```
function increment(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/increment',
        data: {'id': <%= @voiture.id %>},
        method: 'POST' // Add this line!
    });  
}

# routes.rb
post '/increment' => 'voitures#increment'  # change from get to post!

#voitures_controller.rb
def increment
  Voiture.find(params[:id]).increment(:compteur, 1) # fixed line
end
```

Comment: I was going to say the same thing that this isn't really a GET route. It's probably a PUT/PATCH or POST.

Comment: I fixed it by adding render nothing: true to the increment function, but i think your solution is better, thanks man !

Comment: Oups, it didn't work actually, i got this : NoMethodError - undefined method `increment_counter' for #<Voiture:0x007fcb9a4d8128>: (?) !

Comment: @Remis07 I fixed my answer

Comment: @itsnikolay Thanks man, it works! But i had to add this line to the function render nothing: true !